# get album images directly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `AGImagePickerController` for selecting the multiple images at a time and get their information. It is working fine. But I also want that when I click on any album, I get that album images data without going to its detail page.

In

```
self.assetsGroups..:(
    "ALAssetsGroup - Name:Saved Photos, Type:Saved Photos, Assets count:2"
)
```

I am getting Album info but don't know how to get its images without open album detail page. If anyone know how to get it please help me out.

Thanks in advance.